# How can I make unwrapping this optional in Swift, a little more elegant?

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

Unwrapping optionals can be done in a few different ways, but I find myself using only one way, often.

```
func keyboardDidShow(keyboardRect: CGRect?) {
    var height: CGFloat?
    if let rectHeight = keyboardRect?.height {
        height = rectHeight
    } else {
        height = 0
    }
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: height!, right: 0)

    ///...clipping rest of method
}
```

How would you reduce the number of lines here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular example you could use [nil-coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) `??`:

```
func keyboardDidShow(keyboardRect: CGRect?) {
    let height = keyboardRect?.height ?? 0
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: height, right: 0)

    ///...clipping rest of method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for height to be optional, because it will always get a value. And with the latest compiler, there is no need for it to be a var. You can have a constant that will be initialised on both branches of an if. Of course the ?? operator works just fine in this case.